# ¿Como ajustar ventana del navegador al ancho del documento en HTML?

Tags: html

Poseo una tabla grande hecha en html que se genera con registros de una base de datos.

El problema es que: **Aparece un espacio en blanco casi del mismo ancho de la tabla a un lado**

Quedando asi:

```
/* Navegador Web  */
/*********/*********
*        *         *
*  HTML  *  VACIO  *
*        *         *
*********/*********/
/*    Botones     */
```

El primer cuadro es la tabla y el 2do es el espacio vacio.

Si alejas el documento con el ZOOM del navegador el espacio vacio aparece incluso debajo del HTML

Como puedo adaptar para que la tabla o el navegador no salga con tanto espacio o salga en su defecto centrado.

Aqui dejo una foto del problema:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

> Abran la foto

Comment: Hola, Victor, buenos días. Quieres que la tabla se ajuste a lo ancho de tu navegador?

Comment: me gustaria que no salga tanto espacio vacio en el navegador, el fondo se repite en mosaico y la ventana sale como se ve en la foto de la pregunta.

si se adapta el ancho del html no quedaria mal?

Comment: Sí que quedaría mal. Así como se ve en tu snipper se ve bonito. Normalmente los inicios de sesión así son, centrados y pequeños. Si se hacen a lo ancho y largo de la pantalla quedaría mal la vdd. Dices que la ventana sale como en la foto ¿o sea que lo que está en el snipper no es como realmente sale en tu ventana?

Comment: publicare el HTML que me esta dando problemas, porque este que puse puede quedar asi

Comment: Y poner un simple `<table style="float: center; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto;">`? A veces eso queda más bonito que ponerlo a `width: 100%;`

Comment: @Lukas colocalo de respuesta, me funciono perfecto

Comment: @VictorA. me alegro de que te funcione ! Está listo

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Podrías poner:

```
<table style="float: center; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto;">
   // Lo que sea ...
</table>
```

Eso hará que tú tabla sea centrada y el espacio vacío quedaría dividido.

A veces eso queda más bonito que ponerlo a pantalla completa, pero de todos modos te doy indicación de como hacerlo:

```
<table style="width: 100%;">
   // Lo que sea ...
</table>
```